# Flask import error "cannot import name 'Flask'"

Tags: python, flask, module, pip

I am trying to use the python module flask, and I have successfully installed it with pip. I can run the following in the command prompt python terminal and in the python shell:

```
    from flask import Flask
```

It works just fine. However, when I try to run that exact same command in a saved python document, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\flask.py", line 1, in <module>
        from flask import Flask
      File "C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\flask.py", line 1, in <module>
        from flask import Flask
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'
```

I have browsed the internet and stack exchange looking for a solution, but non have worked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rename the filename `flask.py` to other name; It prevents import of the third-party `flask` module because your file is searched first.

Also make sure there's no `flask.pyc` file remaining.

Comment: where can I find these files?

Comment: @Matthew, As the error message suggest, you can find it in `C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop` directory. (maybe your desktop)

Comment: that is the name of my python code file

Comment: @Matthew, I know. The script filename `flask.py` prevent proper import of `flask` module because two name conflict; Rename the script filename to other name.

Comment: @Matthew, Also make sure there's no `C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\flask.pyc` remain as noted in the answer.

Comment: sorry, I misinterpreted what you were saying. Now it works perfectly thanks!